# Directory traversal with chdir() instead of with absolute paths

Tags: c, unix, directory, chdir, directory-walk

In Chapter 4 of the book "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment," which covers files and directories, there is a code sample which aims to be like the `ftw` command and traverse a file hierarchy.  It uses a pointer to an absolute file path, as well as a recursive function with a callback to traverse the directory, using calls to `opendir()` and `readdir()` in the process.

There is an exercise in which readers are asked to use `chdir()` and file names instead of using the absolute paths to accomplish the same task and to compare the times of the two programs.  I wrote a program using `chdir()` and did not notice a difference in the time.  Is this expected?  I would have thought that the additional call to `chdir()` would add some overhead.  Is it maybe a relatively trivial call?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's the recursive function using absolute paths:

```
static int                  /* we return whatever func() returns */
dopath(Myfunc* func)
{
    struct stat     statbuf;
    struct dirent   *dirp;
    DIR             *dp;
    int             ret;
    char            *ptr;

    if (lstat(fullpath, &statbuf) < 0) /* stat error */
        return(func(fullpath, &statbuf, FTW_NS));
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode) == 0) /* not a directory */
        return(func(fullpath, &statbuf, FTW_F));

     /*
      * It's a directory. First call func() for the directory,
      * then process each filename in the directory.
      */
    if ((ret = func(fullpath, &statbuf, FTW_D)) != 0)
        return(ret);

    ptr = fullpath + strlen(fullpath);      /* point to end of fullpath */
    *ptr++ = '/';
    *ptr = 0;

     if ((dp = opendir(fullpath)) == NULL)     /* can't read directory */
         return(func(fullpath, &statbuf, FTW_DNR));

     while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
         if (strcmp(dirp->d_name, ".") == 0 ||
             strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") == 0)
                 continue;        /* ignore dot and dot-dot */

         strcpy(ptr, dirp->d_name);   /* append name after slash */

         if ((ret = dopath(func)) != 0)          /* recursive */
              break; /* time to leave */
     }
     ptr[-1] = 0;    /* erase everything from slash onwards */

     if (closedir(dp) < 0)
         err_ret("can't close directory %s", fullpath);

     return(ret);
}
```

And here's the function with my changes:

```
static int                  /* we return whatever func() returns */
dopath(Myfunc* func, char* path)
{
    struct stat     statbuf;
    struct dirent   *dirp;
    DIR             *dp;
    int             ret;

    if (lstat(path, &statbuf) < 0) /* stat error */
        return(func(path, &statbuf, FTW_NS));
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode) == 0) /* not a directory */
        return(func(path, &statbuf, FTW_F));

 /*
 * It's a directory. First call func() for the directory,
 * then process each filename in the directory.
 */
    if ((ret = func(path, &statbuf, FTW_D)) != 0)
        return(ret);

    if ( chdir(path) < 0 )
      return(func(path, &statbuf, FTW_DNR));

     if ((dp = opendir(".")) == NULL)     /* can't read directory */
         return(func(path, &statbuf, FTW_DNR));

     while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
         if (strcmp(dirp->d_name, ".") == 0 ||
             strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") == 0)
                 continue;        /* ignore dot and dot-dot */

         if ((ret = dopath(func, dirp->d_name)) != 0)          /* recursive */
              break; /* time to leave */
     }
     if ( chdir("..") < 0 )
       err_ret("can't go up directory");

     if (closedir(dp) < 0)
         err_ret("can't close directory %s", fullpath);

     return(ret);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should expect a substantial time performance difference between the absolute path version and the `chdir()` version. Rather, the pros and cons of both versions are as follows:

- The full pathname version might not be able to traverse very deep directory structures because the length of the full pathname eventually exceeds `PATH_MAX`. The `chdir()` version does not have this problem.
- The `chdir()` version manipulates the pwd, which is generally considered bad practice if you can avoid it: it's not thread-safe, and the end user might expect it to be left alone. For example filenames given on the command line and used by a different part of the program might be relative to what the user thought the pwd was, which breaks when you change it.
- The `chdir()` version might go out of control when backing up to a higher directory (`chdir("..")`) if special care is not taken and the directory structure changes while it is being traversed. Then again the full pathname version might break in a different way under these circumstances...

The `openat()` family of functions available on modern POSIX systems offer the best of both worlds. If these functions are available, `openat()` together with `fdopendir()`, `fstatat()`, etc... make for a really nice implementation of directory walking.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and the other functions!